# Deployment Assembly from eclipse to ant script

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, ant

In my eclipse I had a workspace with a dynamic web project with 5 subproject. I create a build.xml file over the export function from the eclipse. The build script works fine. The next step is, I want to create a war file. In the dynamic web project I had the deployment assembly to deploy some jar files and some other files.

Is there a way to get the list of files from the deployment assembly to the ant script or use this list in the ant script ?

Comment: The same problem exists on JavaEE EAR project.